# Obtaining image details in detailviewcontroller when clicking image in collectionviewcontroller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

My CollectionViewController contains an image. When I click the image in my CollectionViewController it takes me to the detailviewcontroller where I want to edit the details of the image. When I enter the details such as an URL, then click the back button, it should fetch the image from the URL and replace the image in my CollectionViewController.

I have two problems:

- When I click the image in my CollectionViewController it opens the detailviewcontroller, but it doesn't show the url of the image I clicked.
- When I click the back button it does not take me back to the CollectionViewController.

```
import Foundation

class Photo {
  var url: String = ""
  var data: NSData? = nil
  var Title: String = ""
  var Tags: String = ""

  func loadImage(completionHandler: (data: NSData?) ->Void) {
    let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0)
    dispatch_async(queue) {
      let mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue()
      if let url = NSURL(string: self.url) {
        if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
          sleep(3)
          dispatch_async(mainQueue) {
            self.data = data
            completionHandler(data: data)
          }
          return
        }

        dispatch_async(mainQueue) {
          completionHandler(data: nil)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

detailviewcontroller

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

  var photo: Photo!

  @IBOutlet weak var textURL: UITextField!

  @IBOutlet weak var textTitle: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var textTags: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

  func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    let urlString = textField.text
    photo.url = urlString
    let DatatoImage: (NSData?) -> Void = {
      if let d = $0 {
        let image = UIImage(data: d)
        self.imageView.image = image
      } else {
        self.imageView.image = nil
      }
      //textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    if let d = photo.data {
      DatatoImage(d)
      textField.resignFirstResponder()
      let image = UIImage(data: d)
      self.imageView.image = image
    } else {
      photo.loadImage(DatatoImage)
    }
    return true
  }
}
```

My masterViewController

```
import UIKit

let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class PhotosCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

  var photos = Array<Photo>()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let photo = Photo()
    photo.url = "http://www.griffith.edu.au/__data/assets/image/0019/632332/gu-header-logo.png"

    photos.append(photo)

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Register cell classes
    self.collectionView!.registerClass(PhotoCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

  override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of sections
    return 1
  }


  override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return photos.count
  }

  override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as PhotoCollectionViewCell

    let photo = photos[indexPath.row]
    if let d = photo.data {
      let image = UIImage(data: d)
      cell.imageView.image = image

      photo.url = "\(photo.url)"
      photo.Title = "\(photo.Title)"
    } else {
      photo.loadImage {
        if $0 != nil {
          collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])
        }
      }
    }
    return cell
  }

  // Uncomment this method to specify if the specified item should be highlighted during tracking
  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let indexPath = sender as? NSIndexPath {
      let photo = photos[indexPath.row]
    }
    if (segue.identifier == "showDetail") {
      if let dvc = segue.destinationViewController as? ViewController {
        let photo = Photo()
        dvc.photo = photo
      }
    }
  }

  override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldHighlightItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetail", sender: indexPath)
    return true
  }
```

Comment: I have edited quite a lot in your question. Please view the revision to see all that has been changed and how you can ask a better question next time. There are two comments in (between `<!--` and `-->`) that you need to look at. When asking a question, please make sure to format your code and to ONLY include code that is necessary to reproduce the problem. You commented out a lot of the code - just remove it when asking a question. Please format your code consistently when asking a question.

Comment: The whitespace in your question was all over the place, and you place brackets (`{` and `}`) sometimes on a newline, sometimes behind the line itself. The same goes for if-else statements, where sometimes `else` is behind the `}` for the corresponding if, and sometimes you split if and else with 2 newlines. Improving on that will make it easier to read your code and find what is wrong with it, and thus increases the chance of someone answering your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your prepareForSegue method, you have this line,

```
let photo = Photo()
```

This creates a new Photo object, it doesn't get the one you were displaying in the cell you selected. You got a reference to the correct one in your if let statement. Use that one (`let photo = photos[indexPath.row]`).

As for the back button, you shouldn't have to write any code to make that work, if that back button is the one you get automatically when you push to a new controller.

Comment: Thanks a lot..
thanks a lot for the reply. But when I change my Photo( ) to photos[indexpath.row], I get an error in my Viewdidload( ) in my ViewController.